# Empty map error for MODIS NDVI time series on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis, time-series

I am trying to get a time series of MODIS NDVI for a point, with the script below and it works quite well, except when I try to include the year 2017 where I get the following error message:

> ID: B4E7LMH7MMFMCKFWYPOAGT2E Phase: Failed Runtime: 28m (started
> 2022-02-15 15:37:39 +0100) Attempted 1 time Error: Error in
> map(ID=159): Image.reduceRegions: Need 1 bands for Reducer.mean, image
> has 0. (Error code: 3)

Apparently, my mapping function must be coming up with an empty image. Someone had suggested to me to use the `ee.ImageCollection​` method `getRegion()`. However, I don't know how it works and how to solve this problem.

Here is the script:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection(point)    

function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  };
}
var ptsTopo = pts.map(bufferPoints(500, false));

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09GA_NDVI')
            .select('NDVI')
            .filterDate('2003-01-01','2017-12-31')
            .map(function(img){var d = ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start')));
              var m = ee.Number(d.get('month'));
              var y = ee.Number(d.get('year'));
              return img.set({'month':m, 'year':y});
            });
              
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List([2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]);
                    
var byYearMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function(y){
        return months.map(function(m){
          return modis.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', y)
                      .filterMetadata('month', 'equals', m)
                      .select('NDVI').mean()
                      .set('year', y)
                      .set('month', m)
                      .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
        });
      
      }).flatten()
      );
      
      
var proj = ee.Image(modis.first()).projection()

var NDVI_pts = byYearMonth.map(function(img){
  var features = ptsTopo.map(function(f) {return f.set('date', img.get('date'), 'month', img.get('month'), 'year', img.get('year'))})
  return img.reduceRegions(features, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, proj);
  
}).flatten();
//print(NDVI_pts.limit(10));

Export.table(NDVI_pts, 'NDVI_pts', {fileFormat: 'CSV'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably comes from an image that doesn't contain any unmasked pixels for the region you're reducing. You could solve it by using `reduceRegion()` instead of `reduceRegions()`. You will then get features without your NDVI property, that you optionally could filter out.

```
var NDVI_pts = byYearMonth
  .map(function(img) {
    return ptsTopo
      .map(function(f) {
        return ee.Feature(
          f.geometry(),
          img.reduceRegion({
            reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
            geometry: f.geometry(), 
            scale: 500
          })
        ).set('date', img.get('date'), 'month', img.get('month'), 'year', img.get('year'))
      })
  })
  .flatten()
  // .filterMetadata('NDVI', 'not_equals', null)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2ee7cecafdb5f59f7925b585c5026aec

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly for exporting the results, but it does not solve the problem of empty values in the dates from April 2017. Does this mean that there is no MODIS NDVI data on these dates?

Comment: You only have imagery Jan, Feb, Mar in 2017: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9f4c160f6d9d4e9b9cc33edd3d63c5f

Comment: So yes, there are months where you don't have any data at all. This triggered an error in your original script.